# Multi-Device Hybrid app AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am trying to make a Multi-Device hybrid app work, but I am getting this error:

> Please Install Android Target 19

Although I have installed Android SDK API 20, I was thinking of changing the Target Android SDK in AndroidManifest file to 20.

I made an `XML` file and added it to the `res/cert/Android` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <manifest>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="20"
              android:targetSdkVersion="20"
              android:maxSdkVersion="20" />
</manifest>
```

Now I am getting the error `Namespace prefix 'Android' is not defined`.

Do you please know how to make it work?

**Update**
I just installed Android SDK 19 but it's still not working.[image]

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit. Does this make any difference?

Comment: Just installing Android SDK API 19 should resolve this. Because Cordova 3.6 is not configured to API 20 yet.

Answer (score 0):

MDHA CTP2.0 uses Cordova 3.5.x, which only supports Android API 19. Using that version is the only option at the moment.